Stego problem I can't extract anything from it
I consider the image is embedded with something more stuff. I need an expert for help. Enter the image description here.
The image has all stuff related. We can't extract anything. I tried a lot more today. If you can help me, I'm fine. If not, I'm trying to learn a lot.

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/g6kefu/there_is_1_eth_hidden_in_this_crypto_puzzle_can/ this is the image i try fo solve
